# Chart not updating properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to follow Mike Bostock's tutorial on d3js (http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) to understand how to update charts dynamically but I am facing some hurdles.

In my chart, my bars on the left, rather than being simply removed, are sent behind my chart and I can't figure out why:

JS:

```
var t = 1297110663, // start time (seconds since epoch)
          v = 70, // start value (subscribers)
          data = d3.range(33).map(next); // starting dataset

          function next() {
            return {
              time: ++t,
              value: v = ~~Math.max(10, Math.min(90, v + 10 * (Math.random() - .5)))
            };
          }

          setInterval(function(){
            data.shift();
            data.push(next());
            console.log(data);
            redraw();
          }, 1000);

          var w = 20,
              h =80;

          var x = d3.scale.linear()
                  .domain([0, 1])
                  .range([0, w]);
          var y = d3.scale.linear()
                  .domain([0, 100])
                  .rangeRound([0, h]);

          var chart = d3.select(".container").append("svg")
              .attr("class", "chart")
              .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
              .attr("height", h);

          chart.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x", function(d, i){ return x(i) - 0.5; })
            .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; })
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

          function redraw(){
            console.log(data);
            var rect = chart.selectAll('rect')
              .data(data, function(d){ return d.time; });

            rect.enter().insert("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i + 1) - .5; })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return h - y(d.value) - .5; })
              .attr("width", w)
              .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.value); })

            rect.transition() // Shouldn't I use .update() here?
              .duration(1000)
              .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) - .5; });

            rect.exit().transition()
              .duration(1000)
              .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i - 1) - .5})
              .remove();
          }
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kkMR4/

Another thing I don't understand is why we dont use .update()? If I understand correctly .enter() is used to create the DOM element where data didnt find any match in the DOM and .exit() is used to find the DOM elements which are not in data, so shouldn't I use update() to move all the other column to the left?

Many thanks

Best

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this block:

```
        rect.exit().transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .attr('x', function(d, i) { return x(i - 1) - .5})
          .remove();
```

The third line (`.attr`), reassigns the coordinates. If you want them to truly exit, you can remove this line.

```
        rect.exit().transition()
          .duration(1000)
          .remove();
```